# How to make circle shape buttons in codenameone with GUI builder

Tags: codenameone

How to make circle button using codenameone gui builder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a 9-piece border which is inherently flawed for round elements just use a [multi-image](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---fetch-an-image-from-the-resource-file---add-a-multiimage.html) of a circle and set it to the background image of the component with a "scale to fit" background type. Make sure to [override the border to be "empty"](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/basics.html) in the designer.

Add padding (ideally in millimeters) to create a sense of size.

Comment: Great. BTW when an answer to a question is correct you need to click the checkbox next to the answer to accept it.